# How to add sonar in the antbuildfile in Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant, sonarqube

I dont understand XML,
But Looking the Tutorial, i created the ant builfile -> projecBuilder.xml in the web application Project in Eclipse (GWT)
With help of projectBuilder.xml i create a jar file for all the java files in client, shared , server.

Now i want to add Sonar as a target in projectbuilder.xml.

I have dowloaded sonar 2.12,
sonar ant task. both are in in Drive D:/

What i have done :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<target name="create_jars" depends='create_jars_client,create_jars_server,
    create_jars_shared,sonar' /> 

        <!--Client-->
    <target name="create_jars_client">
        <echo message = 'Remove Existing Jars'/>
        <delete file="com/example/TryAnt/Client/TryAnt.jar" />
                    <echo message='Create new jars' />
        <jar basedir='${classes}' jarfile="com/example/TryAnt/Client/TryAnt.jar"
                includes ='WEB-INF\classes\com\example\TryAnt\client\TryAnt.class'/>


  </target>
   <!--... Similar more code for creating jar-->
```

[a link](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task)

i used above link link to solve further .

i copied paste the code but it show me error.
Please tell me what are the things to be changed.

please any one can explain me how to analyse code in sonar by using ant build file  in a very simple language.

Comment: Seems you need to read the Sonar ANT doco: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FInally i solved it with help of many blogs and want to share with everyone.

1.Download Ant  http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
2.Unzip it and rename it to ant
3.SET enviornment variable , to do it on command prompt type this (Assume Ant is installed in D:\ant.)

```
    set ANT_HOME=D:\ant
    set JAVA_HOME=CC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30
    set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin
```

4. Check ANT works correctly or not. In the command prompt, type:

   ```
               ant -version
   ```

5.Do not close Command Prompt

Add Sonar

1.Download Sonar 2.12 from link      http://www.sonarsource.org/downloads/
2.Unzip the Download .
3.On windows command prompt  execute       bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat 
4.Browse to http://localhost:9000
5.For administration features, default login/password is admin/admin

For Analyzing with Ant

1.Download Sonar Ant Task  from link    http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE44/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Ant+Task
2.Copy this jar File  sonar-ant-task-1.3 to  lib of Ant folder (D:\ant\lib).
3.Copy jar file to eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20110505-1300

Ant file for the project in Eclipse.

1.For Creating a Ant File in eclipse    check link 
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-93_project_builder.htm

2.In buid.xml
Write code

```
    <property name="classes" location="location\of\class\file"/>
<property name="src" location="location\of\src"/>
<property name="sonar.host.url" value="http://localhost:9000/" />
<target name="sonar_task" depends = 'sonar'/>


<taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
<classpath path="...\ eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20110505-1300\lib\sonar-ant-task-1.3.jar" />
</taskdef>
```

```
                <!-- list of mandatories Sonar properties -->
                <sources>
                     <path location="${src}" />
                </sources>

                <!-- binaries directories, which contain for example the compiled Java bytecode (optional) -->
                <binaries>
                     <path location="${classes.dir}" />
                </binaries>
            </sonar:sonar>

        </target>
```